# will_paginate does not work in partial

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination

I am making site with videos. Each video could be commented in show.html.erb. Because number of comments could be big I made pagination for comments using will_paginate. When creating/deleting new comments I want to update comments list and pagination bar. I can't manage comments and pagination to be updated remotely and to work well.

My model

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :description, :name, :src, :rating, :tag_list
    acts_as_taggable
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments

    validates :rating, presence: true, numericality: {:greater_than_or_equal_to => 0, :less_than_or_equal_to => 1000000}
    validates_uniqueness_of :src
    validates :name, presence: true
    validates :src, presence: true

    after_initialize :init

    def init
      self.rating  ||= 0           #will set the default value only if it's nil
    end
  end
```

I have view videos/show.html.erb

```
<p>Name: <%= @video.name %></p>
<p>Description: <%= @video.description %></p>
<div id="comments_form">
<%= render :partial => "comments/comment",
       :collection => @comments %>
<%= will_paginate @comments %>
</div>
<div id="new_comment_form">
<%= render "comments/form" if current_user%>
</div>
```

I have partial comments/_form.html.erb

```
<%if @user%>
<%= form_for([@video.user, @video, @video.comments.build], remote: true) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>   
 <br />
<div class="field">
 <%= f.label "Сообщение" %> 
 <br />
 <%= f.text_field :body %> 
 <br/>
</div>
<div class="actions">
<%= submit_tag "Добавить сообщение", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %> 
</div>
<% end %>
<%end%>
```

My comments/_comment.html.erb

```
<p>
<%if comment.user%> 
  <b><%= comment.user.name %></b> (создано <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> назад): 
<%end%> 
<%= comment.body %>
<%if comment.user == current_user%>
  <%= link_to "Удалить сообщение", [comment.video.user, comment.video, comment],
                                   :confirm => "Уверен?",
                                   :method => :delete, remote: true %>
  <%end%>

</p>
```

I have controller controllers/comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
...
def create
    @video=Video.find(params[:video_id])
    @comment = @video.comments.new(params[:comment])
    @comment.user = current_user
    @video=Video.find(params[:video_id]) unless @comment.save
    @comments = @video.comments.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10, order: 'created_at DESC')
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end     
end
 ...
end
```

I have comments\create.js.erb

```
$("#comments_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "comments/comment",
       :collection => @comments) %><%= escape_javascript(will_paginate @comments) %>")
```

Everything is almost great: my new comment is created, my pagination bar is updated, but links instead of /users/1/videos/17?page=1 are /users/1/videos/17/comments?page=1
I tried hard for two days to find out how to fix this problem, but no use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the pagination bar is updated in the videos/comments#create.  By default, the pagination controller/action are the index of the current controller.  You can force the controller/action when generating the pagination links by using the [will_paginate params option](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/API-documentation#view-template-helpers).

TBH, I would consider using videos/comments#index for listing comments instead of videos#show.

Comment: Thanks. I used videos/comments#index for listing and rendered 'render template: "videos/show"' in comments#index, every works well. Big thank for fast reply!